# Listings, keywords with backslash in them

Tags: listings

This probably have an answer on here somewhere...

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{level1}{red}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{level1},
  alsoletter={\\},
}
\begin{document}
\lstset{
  morekeywords={\\bigl,\\bigr}
}

\begin{lstlisting}
$\bigl(\sqrt{x^2}\bigr)$
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
$ \bigl(\sqrt{x^2}\bigr)$
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Why do I need a space in order to get a red `\bigl`?

[image]

Comment: The math shift is also a letter, so listings see the "keyword" `$\bigl`. You could add `alsoother={$}`

Comment: Nice one thanks. Write an answer if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The math shift is also a letter, so listings see the "keyword" `$\bigl`. You could add `alsoother={$}`.

## Edit

Probably a better way is to define an own language:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{level1}{red}

\lstdefinelanguage{daleif}{%
 moretexcs={bigr}}%default keywords
[keywords,tex,comments] %aspects

\lstset{
  language=daleif,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  texcsstyle=*\bfseries\color{level1},
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
$\bigr\bigl\def$
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[moretexcs={bigl}]
$\bigr\bigl\def$
\end{lstlisting}


\begin{lstlisting}
$\bigr\bigl\def$
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Are there other caveats one need to keep a look at? I'm displaying LaTeX code, but is not declaring LaTeX as a language. I just want to use `morekeywords` to specify which parts to highlight in a given `lstlisting`.

Comment: Well you will get problems if you write keywords without separation `\bigr\bigl` will no be recogized.

Comment: I've noticed. Seams it is easier to load `LaTeX`, reset the keywords lists, and use `texcs` and `moretexcs` locally.

Comment: Hmm, that is not that stable either...

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "not stable". But I guess your main goal it to color the backslashes right? I think I had once some code but I will have to look.

Comment: Something like that. Basically all the text is black, and I just want to highlight the relevant parts.

Comment: Then you probably should use your own language, see my edit. An alternative is to use moredelim to manually mark the parts that should be highlighted.

Comment: Probably, just tried to highlight `[r]` didn't work much either. I'll look into writing my own language. I usually use `\lstset` within environments/blocks to set the various keywords/highlights.